# What is the best framework to use for back-end of a website that has search functionality, and add/update records functionality

Tags: web-apps, web-development, api, framework, web-apis

What is the best framework to use for back-end of a website that has search functionality, and add/update records functionality?
I'm using VUE.JS for the front-end and thinking about utilizing Azure Functions for the APIs. Is this efficient and/or cost effective if a lot of people use it?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 1):

The zoo of awesome backend frameworks that would perfectly suit your use case is huge.

Thus, what defines the choice is not so much the frameworks themselves but the availability of suitably trained/skilled people *to you*. See what skills you can get, and from there choose the tools.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful reply sir. I'm a pro at Azure functions, and can whip up APIs using that in minutes. However, I'm all new in this world, and I'm not sure if nodejs would be better or Azure functions.

Comment: like things that come to my mind, if we theorize that a lot of people will use the website, will Azure functions be as fast/efficient as nodejs? Will it have similar costs? Or is the difference between those two are far too great and I'm missing something?